# Writing unsigned int of 4 bytes over network

Tags: java, networking, casting, long-integer, unsigned

I have problem writing an unsigned 4 bytes int in java.

Either writing a long value in java has different result on 64 bit MacOS and 32 bit Linux (Ubuntu)
OR
Writing to network a 4 byte unsigned int has a problem.

The following call works perfectly on my local OSX

```
writeUInt32(999999,outputstream)
```

Reading it back gives me 999999

However when the application is deployed to a network writing a long value results in some other random number (I assume the endian has been switched?) and reading it gives me some other large number.

---------- The complete method stack is as below---------------

```
public void writeUInt32(long uint32,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        writeUInt16((int) (uint32 & 0xffff0000) >> 16,stream);
        writeUInt16((int) uint32 & 0x0000ffff,stream);
    }

public void writeUInt16(int uint16,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        writeUInt8(uint16 >> 8, stream);
        writeUInt8(uint16, stream);
    }

public void writeUInt8(int uint8,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.write(uint8 & 0xFF);
    }
```

Edit: To add to the confusion writing to a file and then transporting it over the network sends me the correct value! So when outputstream points to a local file then it writes the correct values but when outputstream points to a ByteArrayOutputStream then the long value written is wrong.

Comment: why wouldn't you just use stream.writeInt((int) uint32);

Comment: because int cannot hold as much as long so it will lose value. I have to store 4 bytes of data in an long instead of int because in java an int is signed and a bit is always assigned to the "sign" and hence a int in java holds less value than an unsigned int in c

Comment: no, a java int doesn't hold any less information.  it's the same bits, it's just how you interpret them.

Comment: Are you reading from Java program or C program?  DataOutputStream always writes big endian, but reading `int` from C program will be a subject to the platform endianness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use DataOutput/InputStream.

To write, cast your `long` to `int`

```
public void writeUInt32(
      long uint32,
      DataOutputStream stream
    ) throws IOException
{
    stream.writeInt( (int) uint32 );
}
```

On read, use readInt, assign to long and mask top 32 bits to get unsigned value.

```
public long readUInt32(
      DataInputStream stream
    ) throws IOException
{
    long retVal = stream.readInt( );

    return retVal & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL;
}
```

**EDIT**

From your questions, looks like you are confused about Java cast conversions and promotions for primitive types.

Read this section of Java Spec on Conversions and Promotions: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html

Comment: Won't casting (int) uint32 will roll over all values that are larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE even though the long can hold values larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: The reason I chose long to hold an int value is because the int is unsigned and the only way to hold an unsigned int in java is to declare it as long. Some values above Integer.MAX_VALUE are integers in C since the maximum length of integer in java is smaller due to 1 bit being assigned to the sign value

Comment: @Ganesh. Casting `long` to `int` is fine as long ( no pun intended ) as you guarantee that uint32 holds only 4 bytes of data.  In the process the `int` value may become signed ( if the original `long` is bigger than 0x7FFFFFFFL ), but that's taken care of in the readUInt32 by casting it back to `long` and masking off higher 32 bits.

Comment: @Ganesh. I've added link to a java spec that explains cast promotion.

Comment: What if other implementation, e.g. done in C, reads the result of writeUInt32 as uint would they receive the same value? I wonder, as in their case they would not process it as done in readUInt32.

Comment: @Boro. `C` has a concept of `unsigned int`, `java` does not.  What's important is that if you put 4 bytes of data that represents `unsigned int` concept, then `C` will correctly interpret that on its end.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak This is what I suspected though want to verify. Thank you.